# checked and unchecked in react native not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am totally new to react native and I don't know whether it is correct way to do or not. I am using checkbox component from `@react-native-community/checkbox`. I am getting set of services from API. In that APi I am getting `isCheked = false` by default. When I clicked on checked box it is working fine and when un-checking it is not working.  I don't know where I am going wrong.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Text, View, Picker, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
import {apiUrl} from '../../utilities/index';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import axios from 'axios';

const BookingCreate = ({route, navigation}) => {
const [services, setServices] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
      axios
        .get(apiUrl + `salonService/salonID/${route.params.salonId}`, {
          headers: {
            auth: await AsyncStorage.getItem('token'),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          setServices(res.data.servicesList);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          alert(e);
        });
  }, [route.params.salonId]);

const changeCheckboxValue = (id) => {
    const data = services;
    const index = data.findIndex((x) => x._id === id);
    data[index].isChecked = data[index].isChecked ? false : true;
    setServices(data);
  };

return (
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
{services.length != 0 ? (
            services.map((item) => (
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}
                  onPress={() => changeCheckboxValue(item._id)}>
                  <CheckBox
                    value={item.isChecked}
                    onAnimationType="fill"
                    offAnimationType="fade"
                    boxType="square"
                    onValueChange={() => changeCheckboxValue(item._id)}
                  />
                  <Text style={{marginLeft: 10}}>{item.serviceId.name}</Text>
                  <Text style={{marginLeft: 10}}>{item.category}</Text>
                  <Text style={{marginLeft: 10}}>{item.price}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            ))
          ) : (
            <Text>Loading</Text>
          )}
</View>

)

}

export default BookingCreate;
```

Comment: Change const data = services; to const data = [...services];

Comment: if u don't mind what is difference between ```data = services;``` and  ```const data = [...services]; ```.

Comment: hey it is working fine but when I click on touchable opacity it is not working. If I clicked on only checkbox it is working now

Comment: @sigmato `[...services]` is a *way* to shallow copy an array into a new array reference.

Comment: @sigmato hope the answer by Drew Reese makes it clear :), still having issue with checkbox?

Comment: Yeah very much clear now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Your issues appears to be state mutation. You are mutating the state object, and nested property at a specific index, and then saving the same state back, which is a non-op.

```
const changeCheckboxValue = (id) => {
  const data = services; // <-- state reference
  const index = data.findIndex((x) => x._id === id);
  data[index].isChecked = data[index].isChecked ? false : true; // <-- mutation!
  setServices(data); // <-- state reference back to state
};
```

## Solution

Use a functional state update to shallow copy your state. Map the previous state to the next state, and when the element `id` matches, also shallow copy the element and update the `checked` property. You don't actually need to search the `data` array first for an index, you can iterate it once when copying the state into the next state.

```
const changeCheckboxValue = (id) => {
  setServices((data) =>
    data.map((el) => // <-- copy state
      el.id === id
        ? {
            ...el, // copy element to update
            isChecked: !el.isChecked // toggle checked state
          }
        : el
    )
  );
};
```

Comment: thank you very very much it is working fine. I got stuck from last 4 hours but finally working. Thank you once again